# How to use Sequential in CNN Models?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to classify images using different architectures of CNN(Convolutional Neural Network) and i am using keras for implemantation.  To be able to use model.evaluate function i need to use sequential method to implement my model. Here is my CNN architecture (residual model):

```
# example of a CNN model with an identity or projection residual module
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import add
from keras.utils import plot_model
import tensorflow as tf 
# function for creating an identity or projection residual module
def residual_module(layer_in, n_filters):
    merge_input = layer_in
    # check if the number of filters needs to be increase, assumes channels last format
    if layer_in.shape[-1] != n_filters:
        merge_input = Conv2D(n_filters, (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer_in)
    # conv1
    conv1 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer_in)
    # conv2
    conv2 = Conv2D(n_filters, (3,3), padding='same', activation='linear', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
    # add filters, assumes filters/channels last
    layer_out = add([conv2, merge_input])
    # activation function
    flatten = Flatten()(layer_out)
    layer_out = Activation('relu')(flatten)
    layer_out = Dense(12, activation='softmax')(layer_out)

    return layer_out
 
# define model input
visible = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
# add vgg module
layer = residual_module(visible, 64)
# create model
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=layer)
# summarize model
model.summary()
# plot model architecture
```

I want to change this model using sequential method like following:

```
model= Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', activation `='relu',input_shape=(256,256,3)))`
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))


model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(12,activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [layers](https://keras.io/api/layers/#:~:text=Layers%20are%20the%20basic%20building,variables%20(the%20layer's%20weights).), [sequential model](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/) check these out, you will get it

Comment: Functional Models also have the evaluate method, there is no need to convert to sequential